# How to load custom slice images with leaflet js

Tags: leaflet

i got a link http://thematicmapping.org/playground/zoomify/example.html
this link use some free plugin to load custom images by leaflet js

### here small code

```
var map = L.map('photo').setView(new L.LatLng(0,0), 0);

L.tileLayer.zoomify('http://thematicmapping.org/playground/zoomify/books/', {
    width: 5472,
    height: 3648,
    tolerance: 0.8,
    attribution: 'Photo: Bjørn Sandvik'
}).addTo(map);
```

but i do not want to use any plugin. so just curious to know is it possible to load custom slice images with leaflet js. if yes then please drive to right article or code sample which help me to construct it.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is a bit delayed, but you can do this by adding your own images into folders names by zoom level {z}. You can include them like this:

```
L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/map_{x}_{y}.png', {
```

Here's a good description how to convert your image into the correct slices:

http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/

Comment: can u tell me how to save the multiple marker related info in db and later load it from db again to display on images.

Comment: please share knowledge if u know....z is for zoom but what zoom does in leaflet js? when we specify url localhost/tileserver{z}/{x}/{y}.png for loading tile image then what z does? anyone can elaborately explain the meaning of z/x/y ?

Comment: Thomas, you'll have to convert your large image into tiles as described in this article: http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/ You'll need to do this for each zoom level (i.e. 20 being the maximum size (let's say 10000px x 10000px), 19 being scaled down by half (5000px x 5000px) and pop the tiles into folders named by zoom level (folders named "20" and "19"). You can then set minimum and maximum zoom levels in a way to only allow zooming to level you actually have created tiles for.

Comment: Any idea, to use it in an angular project?